# Rspec: differences between {} and () in expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to use Rspec for testing if a request thrown `RecordNotFound` exception or not. I don't know what is the real differences between those two line of code, but one is work, and one is not.

This line is worked:

```
  expect{get :show, params: {id: promotion.id + 1}}.to raise_exception(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

But this line is not (using () instead of {})

```
  expect(get :show, params: {id: promotion.id + 1}).to raise_exception(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

However, I often use second line for another expect things such as:

```
it 'expect success' do
  get :show, params: {id: product.id}
  expect(response).to be_success
end
```

Please tell me what is the difference.